# Pagination in ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagination

I want to implement `pagination` into my application.

My Controller

```
public ActionResult Leading(string type, int? pageNumber)
{
    IEnumerable<LeadingClass> data;
    LeadingDatabaseHandle DatabaseHandle = new LeadingDatabaseHandle ();
    if (type.HasValue)
    {
        data = DatabaseHandle(type).ToPagedList(pageNumber ?? 1, 10);
    }
    else
    {
        data = DatabaseHandle.LeadingAll().ToPagedList(pageNumber ?? 1, 10);
    }
    LeadingFilterVM model = new LeadingFilterVM
    {
        Type = type,
        TypeList = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem{ Text = "General", Value = "1" },
            new SelectListItem{ Text = "Advance", Value = "2" }
        },  
        Leadings = data
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

My `Data Model

```
public class LeadingClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }  
    public string Name{ get; set; }        
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

My View Model

```
public class LeadingFilterVM
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TypeList { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<LeadingClass> Leadings { get; set; }
}
```

And my View

```
@model Website.Models.Leading.ViewModels.LeadingFilterVM
@using PagedList;
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@using (Html.BeginForm("Leading", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Leadings.FirstOrDefault().Type)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Type, Model.TypeList, "All Type", new { @class = "form-control"})
}
<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Leadings.FirstOrDefault().Id)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Leadings.FirstOrDefault().Name)</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Leadings)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</td>   
        </tr>
    }
</table>

Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount

@Html.PagedListPager(Model, pageNumber => Url.Action("Leading", new
{
    pageNumber   
}))
```

It is throwing error: **Compiler Error Message:**

> CS1061: 'LeadingFilterVM' does not contain a definition for 'PageNumber' and no extension method 'PageNumber' accepting a first argument of type 'LeadingFilterVM' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Can anyone please guide me?

Comment: The message is pretty obvious: `PageNumber` property is not exist in `LeadingFilterVM` viewmodel class. Check if you're using `PageNumber` properly from `PagedListPager`.

Comment: From the code you shared in the question, your `LeadingFilterVM` class does not have a `PageNumber` property. Why are you using that property if you have not defined it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model in the view is `LeadingFilterVM` and that model does not contain a property for `PageNumber`.

Note that there are other issues with your code, and you need to change the view model to

```
public class LeadingFilterVM
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TypeList { get; set; }
    public IPagedList<LeadingClass> Leadings { get; set; } //IPagedList, not IEnumerable
}
```

Then you need to change the view to use the `Leadings` property which is the `IPagedList`

```
Page @(Model.Leadings.PageCount < Model.Leadings.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.Leadings.PageNumber) of @Model.Leadings.PageCount
@Html.PagedListPager(Model.Leadings, page => Url.Action("Leading", new { page, type = Model.Type }))
```

and change the signature of the method to

```
public ActionResult Leading(int? type, int? pageNumber)
```

You also need to change the code to generate the `SelectList` to

```
TypeList = new List<SelectListItem>
{
    new SelectListItem{ Text = "General", Value = "General" },
    new SelectListItem{ Text = "Advance", Value = "Advance" }
},
```

or just simply `TypeList = new SelectList(new string[]{ "General", "Advance" })`, since you need to post back either "General" or "Advance", not an `int`. Having said that, I would recommend that `Type` be in `int` with a FK relationship to a `Types` table in your database.

Note its not clear what your `DatabaseHandle.LeadingAll()` and `DatabaseHandle(type)` methods return, but they should be returing `IQueryable<LeadingClass>` (not `IEnumerable<>` or `IList<>`) otherwise you defeating the benefits of server side paging. The typical code for getting the records would be

```
public ActionResult Leading(string type, int? pageNumber)
{
    IQueryable<LeadingClass> data = db.LeadingClass;
    if (type != null)
    {
        data = data.Where(x => x.Type == type.Value);
    }
    LeadingFilterVM model = new LeadingFilterVM
    {
        ....
        Leadings = data..ToPagedList(pageNumber ?? 1, 10)
    };
    return View(model);
}
```